# Coding convention: Should i restyle already working code?

Tags: coding-style

My friends and I are starting a startup (we don't have much experiences, this is our first big project ever). Since we wanted to get our product to market as soon as possible, we did not care about coding convention at the beginning. Now when the coding is finish, we start to worry about the maintainability of the code. However, since the code is already working, reformatting it will requires a lot of work and we afraid that it may introduced new bugs.

I want to know your opinions on this topic. Is reformatting the code worth it?

Answer (score 1):

Changes in formatting, alignment and indentation should not impact functioning code.  **However**, be careful not to change functionality in terms of standardizing naming conventions (eg: use of singular instead of plurals for collections or vice-versa etc).

Treat it as a single system-wide change if you can with no other changes going in during the process. This will help in doing version comparisons later when tracking down issues.